# Unable to save settings : IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I use IntelliJ IDEA 15 and have a problem with the auto-saving. For example I make a new configuration, e.g. Show the line number. When I close IntelliJ and reopen my IDE, it doesn't save my configuration and shows me this message:

> Unable to save settings : Failed to save settings . Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Try removing the folder `.IntelliJIdeaXX\system` and restarting. It seems like something is corrupted.

Comment: No always same message ... When IntelliJ restart, another file /system be create and I think the problem is not in /system but in the /config file

Comment: You can do the same test and delete de config folder... just make a backup of it before doing so, otherwise you may loose something personal.

Comment: I think i should delete .IntelliJIdea and launch IntelliJ for reinstall the IDE. I see the answer in same case with AndroidStudio. AndroidStudio is an IntelliJ... So I try this solution tomorrow because I don't have a time today. I want communicate you my result

Comment: I delete the .IntelliJIdea15 file and i launch ./idea  again. So i reconfigure all again same first time when you install IntelliJ (config, theme, licence ... :( ) but it's okay now ... this is a solution but I think it's not a very good solution

Comment: try delete .IntelliJIdea file. when you launch ./idea, you should reconfigure your IDE, but maybe you fixe the bug with this action. (that's my case)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I get this too (IntelliJ 15.0.5), but only when the "Markdown support" plugin is used. Once a .md file is visualised the error starts appearing.

For future reference current version: 2016.1.20160405.143

Not a very solution-oriented post, but maybe this can help someone further pinpoint the source of the error.

Comment: If you want to keep "markdown support", this is annoying because your custom markdown css will not be saved. What you can do is save your css to `.IntelliJIdea15/config/plugins/markdown/lib/default.css`. Backup your default.css before doing this.

Comment: My problematic plugin was: Identifier Highlighter (from 2009). Deleting that from .IntelliJIdea16/config/plugins elliminated the problem (however I liked that plugin very much).

Comment: @MiklosJakab I also had the problem with Identifier Highlighter, but don't worry, there is a newer version available, which does not have the issue. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6318?pr=androidstudio

Comment: @Jon Lauridsen Good catch. Was happening on PhpStorm 10.0.4 as well so I removed "Markdown plugin" 2016.1.20160405.143 to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 40):

*This workaround allows you continue using "Markdown Support".*

Uninstall the latest version of "Markdown Support" and install version "8.0.0.20160127.143.1" from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793?pr=idea. Everything works fine.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you want to user markdown support without error.

Comment: This answer solve the problem and allows to use markdown support.

Comment: I was unable to follow this answer. I'm using `2017.1.4`. If i try to use the markdown support with the version you mention above, i get an error "Plugin 'Markdown support' is incompatible with this installation."

Comment: @CasperWilkes This issue is not occurring on 2017.2 EAP. Build #IU-172.2656.10. You may want to try it out.

Comment: thanks @XiaoPeng. I'll have to give it a shot. I'm trying to use it on Centos 7. So far, it's been a pain in the @$$. Hopefully this helps with the errors i'm getting.

Answer (score 11):

I was receiving the error with:

> > - IntelliJ v15.0.6
> > - "Markdown support" plugin version 2016.1.20160405.143

I uninstalled the Markdown support plugin (`IntelliJ` IDEA > Preferences... > Plugins > Markdown support), restarted `IntelliJ`, and am now able to save without error.

Comment: Thanks, "Markdown support" was apparently the culprit for me too. And it appears that the Markdown Navigator plugin is a viable alternative.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried everything from this SO thread but it did not work. I solved it by deleting the `.idea` folder from my project's Windows path and then restarting intellij.

Comment: It works! Also I've... removed all build directories, reloaded gradle projects, and re-built project.

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen when the disk drive where the currently opened project is stored is full (0 bytes left on device). The system tries to write to the .idea folder but cannot, so it gives the same error as if there were no access rights.

This happened to me as there was a process writing to disk in the background until it was full.

Comment: Yep, it certainly can.

Answer (score 2):

I delete this file : `.IntelliJIdea` 
When I launch ./idea I should reconfigure all IntelliJ system (config/ extention/ theme/ licence ...) 
So It's okay now but I think is not a good solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for Windows users.
My installation is located in:

***"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\phpstorm"***

The location gives it problems with the saving of files. (probably to do with user rights and UAC, not totally figured out what rights the folder needs, but for easy resolving I removed and reinstalled Phpstorm to

***"C:\development\phpstorm"*** and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**For those who have a simular issue on windows machines:**

I have applied the "hidden" property for the .[IntelliJ-Produkt][Version] folder in Users/[Username] folder. This was causing the issue. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I open up IDEA for the first time after copying the old config files backed up with my Live CD USB before reinstalling my Ubuntu. I think it is because I copied the files from the old OS and to the new OS as root, so the ownership of the folder is changed. Now when I want to write to it as another user, it blocks me from doing it.

Change the ownership to your user and change permission to add write solves it. You use `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: You left out the key piece of information - which folder?

Comment: `~/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1` or so, in my Ubuntu. Windows may be different.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, I've uninstalled PhpStorm, and then have installed it again, always by using the JetBrains TOOLBOX.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Defender was the issue

Windows defender has a protection component called ransomware protection (details: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/protect-ransomware-windows-defender/)

This restricts folder access (for selected folders) to some programs only.

### Add Webstorm to allowed applications

Excerpt is below. Full guide with pictures are here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-allow-blocked-apps-ransomware-protection-windows-10-october-2018-update

> 1. Open Windows Security.
> 2. Click on Virus & threat protection.
> 3. Under "Ransomware protection," click the Manage ransomware protection option.
> 4. Click the Allow an app through Controlled folder access option.
> 5. Click the Add an allowed app button.
> 6. Click the Recently blocked apps option.
> 7. Click the + (plus) button for the app you trust and want to allow.
> 8. Click the Close button.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and it might help some people if above solutions cant help. I am using dual boot system. Win 8 and Kubuntu. I got this problem with my intellij installed in Kubuntu. I realized my project was in a NTFS partition which was marked as READ ONLY. This happens sometimes when you shutdown windows and start computer into your linux.

Solution is to go back to your windows OS and `restart` it and switch to linux. Also, you could hold `shift` and press shutdown button, then choose to `turn of your pc` in the blue menu.

Answer (score -1):

On windows 10 I had the same problem, I ran PhpStorm as administrator which fixed permission issues it had.
Then I restarted PhpStorm without administrator permissions and everything worked fine.

It was a fresh install so no plugins other then the build in ones.

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this issue multiple times; rebooting my (windows) computer has always worked for me (while restarting Intellij didn't do anything).

Answer (score -1):

It's because you don't have permission to save settings. On my macOS, I set write permission of my project.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an short explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I got same error message for InteliJ **WebStrorm** saying

> Unable to save settings
>   Failed to save settings. Please restart WebStorm

It happened due to permission issue. if you don't have permission to save this message could pop-up. Please make sure you have write permission to the folder you are saving.

Answer (score -3):

I might be late at answering this but I did not see any accepted answers here.

I got a solution to this on other forum.

They suggested to **start IntelliJ IDEA as Administrator**.

It worked for me.

Hope it helps people who come here searching for answers.

Answer (score -3):

for my Ubuntu, i fixed it by issuing this command.
**sudo chmod 777 /path/to/dir**

Comment: Granting all types of permissions for every user is never a good solution from security perspective!